# How do I transform a MongoDB collection to an object keyed on an element's value?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Consider MongoDB's [zip codes aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/) example [data set](http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json).  Each document in the collection looks like the following:

```
{
  "_id": "10280",
  "city": "NEW YORK",
  "state": "NY",
  "pop": 5574,
  "loc": [
    -74.016323,
    40.710537
  ]
}
```

How do I transform the collection into an object where each key is the value of a field and each value is the object in the collection?

For example, given two documents

```
{ "_id" : "01001", "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA" }
{ "_id" : "01002", "city" : "CUSHMAN", "loc" : [ -72.51564999999999, 42.377017 ], "pop" : 36963, "state" : "MA" }
```

how do I transform them into a single document

```
{
  "01001": { "_id" : "01001", "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA" },
  "01002": { "_id" : "01002", "city" : "CUSHMAN", "loc" : [ -72.51564999999999, 42.377017 ], "pop" : 36963, "state" : "MA" }
}
```

?

I'm trying MongoDB shell command `db.zips.aggregate({$project: { "$_id":"$$CURRENT"}}).pretty()`, and I'm getting the error message `$expressions are not allowed at the top-level of $project`.

I also tried using mapReduce with the command `db.zips.mapReduce(function(){emit(this._id, this)},function(k,v){}, {out:"stuffs"})` but that, not surprisingly, just produces (with `db.stuffs.find()`)

```
{ "_id" : "01001", "value" : { "_id" : "01001", "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA" } }
{ "_id" : "01002", "value" : { "_id" : "01002", "city" : "CUSHMAN", "loc" : [ -72.51565, 42.377017 ], "pop" : 36963, "state" : "MA" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cursor method **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** to iterate the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** cursor and access the documents which you can then add to an object variable, as in the following example with the two documents:

```
var obj = {};
var iterator = function(doc){
    obj[doc._id] = doc;
}
db.collection.find({}).forEach(iterator);
printjson(obj);
```

**Output**

```
{
    "01001" : {
        "_id" : "01001",
        "city" : "AGAWAM",
        "loc" : [
            -72.622739,
            42.070206
        ],
        "pop" : 15338,
        "state" : "MA"
    },
    "01002" : {
        "_id" : "01002",
        "city" : "CUSHMAN",
        "loc" : [
            -72.51565,
            42.377017
        ],
        "pop" : 36963,
        "state" : "MA"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @chridam.  I was looking for a query-only way to do this, without a cursor.  I should've been more specific in my question.

Comment: @MatthewAdams, Please use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)